# Force redraw TextView instance

Tags: java, android, xamarin

I have custom span which should be repeatedly redrawn after specific interval.  I try to call `invalidate` method of `TextView` instance but nothing happens.

My custom span is redrawn only when I `append` new text to `TextView` instance.

So, my question is how to achive "force" redraw/invalidate of `TextView` without change it's text?

UPD:
My custom span `TypingAnimationSpan` inherited from `ReplacementSpan`.
On `Draw` method in `TypingAnimationSpan` only part of text is drawing to canvas. On next `Draw` call length of drawing text part is increases.
As result "typing" effect should be achived.

My custom `AnimatedTextView` in `Draw` method checks - are any of it's `TypingAnimationSpan`s are in `animation` state (should be redrawn) and calls `PostInvalidateDelayed`

Part of `TypingAnimationSpan`:

```
    public override void Draw(Canvas canvas, ICharSequence text, int start, int end, float x, int top, int y, int bottom, Paint paint)
    {
        count += 0.1f * Speed;
        count = Math.Min(count, end - start);

        canvas.DrawText(text, start, start + (int) count, x, y, paint);

        IsAnimationRunning = count <= end - start;
    }

    public override int GetSize(Paint paint, ICharSequence text, int start, int end, Paint.FontMetricsInt fm)
    {
        return (int) paint.MeasureText(text, start, start + (int) count);
    }
```

Part of `AnimatedTextView`:

```
    public override void Draw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        base.Draw(canvas);

        var targetSpans = (this.TextFormatted as ISpanned)
            ?.GetSpans(0, this.TextFormatted.Length(), Java.Lang.Class.FromType(typeof(TypingAnimationSpan)))
            ?.ToList();

        bool needInvalidate = targetSpans?.Any(x => ((TypingAnimationSpan ) x).IsAnimationRunning) == true;

        if (needInvalidate)
        {
            this.PostInvalidateDelayed(1);
        }
    }
```

So, I see that `this.PostInvalidateDelayed(1);` is called, but span is not redrawn.

Comment: Just to clarify, the TextView does not change, when you manipulate the span, right? Also please share the code (simplified) you use to change the span and where you set it on the TextView.

Comment: I've edited my post

Comment: The postInvalidate method notifies the system from a non-UIThread and the View gets redrawn in the next eventloop on the UIThread as soon as possible. So it will not update immediately. Did you use `handler` to send a message to notificate UIThread to update the view by `invalidate `method.